# onItemClick stop working after List update

Tags: java, android, listview, layout, onitemclicklistener

I'm developing and application that requires a listView. When I run the app it works fine and I use the following code:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
adapterListView = new AdapterListView(MainActivity.this, itemList);
listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

The Main Activity implements OnItemClickListener and in it I have:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
{
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);
    for(ConsultaAndroid ca : lista_consulta) {
        if(item.getTexto().contains(ca.getNome().toString()) && item.getTexto().contains(ca.getHorario())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("nome", ca.getNome());
            intent.putExtra("rg", ca.getRg());
            intent.putExtra("cpf", ca.getCpf());
            intent.putExtra("datanasc", ca.getDatanasc());
            intent.putExtra("telefone", ca.getTelefone());
            intent.putExtra("celular", ca.getCelular());
            intent.putExtra("email", ca.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra("endereco", ca.getEndereco()+", "+ca.getNumero()+" - "+ca.getBairro()+" - "+ca.getCidade());
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,PacienteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

After that, if I click in a DatePicker, when I set a new date the List should update, and it doed, but the onItemClick stop working.
I'm using the same code inside DatePicker's OnDateSetListener().

Any Ideas why it is happening?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="393dp"
        android:divider="#ECECEC"
        android:dividerHeight="1sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.28"
            android:text="Data" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.28"
            android:text="Sair" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly happening, but you can add break or return to stop the loop after startActivity. But it's not a key point)

layout xml is clean. can you show full MainActivity code?

Comment: Yes!) I know, but don't have enough reputation to add comment. Reputation irony...

Comment: `The first pice of code is in onCreate or onResume method?` Would it matter enough to contribute to the problem? Also, when replying to someone, add @username so that they get to know about your reply.

Comment: @wikram Yep. You're right about onCreate/onResume. Without full code it's hard to give advice.

Comment: Sorry, I can't show the full code .. if there's a particular piece of it or some extra information that I should put here please let me know.